# Having trouble calculating size for resize-partition

Tags: windows, powershell, diskspace

Got a disk with unallocated space before and after a partition. I'm trying to calculate the size that needs to be in resize-partition. Its probably easier to explain the problem through code.
Output 1 being wrong is understandable since there is unallocated space before the partition. Not too sure what partition.offset can be reliably used...

Oh and we cant use the Get-PartitionSupportedSize cause it seems to mess with some of our other operations. Diskpart is also a no go since this runs a lot and we want to minimize powershell opening other programs.

Basically is there any alternative to `Get-PartitionSupportedSize`?

```
$physicalDisk = Get-Disk -Number 2
$partition = Get-Partition -DiskNumber 2
$maxSize = (Get-PartitionSupportedSize -DiskNumber 2).SizeMax
$calcSize = $partition.Size + ($physicalDisk.Size - $physicalDisk.AllocatedSize)
"Output 1"
$maxSize - $calcSize
$calcSize = $partition.Size + ($physicalDisk.Size - $physicalDisk.AllocatedSize) - $partition.Offset
"Output 2"
$maxSize - $calcSize
$calcSize = $physicalDisk.AllocatedSize + $physicalDisk.LargestFreeExtent
"Output 3"
$maxSize - $calcSize
$calcSize = $partition.Size + $physicalDisk.LargestFreeExtent
"Output 4"
$maxSize - $calcSize
```

Results:

> Output 1
>   -132137984
>  Output 2
>  3128320
>  Output 3
>   -1065472
>  Output 4
>  2079744

Comment: `Get-PartitionSupportedSize cause it seems to mess with some of our other operations.` What exactly does this mean?

Comment: We initially deployed code with Get-PartitionSupportedSize. It was a while back but our production application kept crashing occasionally and the timeline matched our resize task. Hence had to take it out. It was a while back so I don't recall all the details.

Comment: I recommend working on figuring that out. I use `Get-PartitionSupportedSize` and the resultant `.MaxSize` and never had any issues; it's the right way to do it. One thing that does look a little weird in your code is that you're using `-DiskNumber`. A disk can have multiple partitions. As written your result could be an array of several numbers. Same with `$partition`. You need a way to single out which partition you want to resize and then get _that one's_ max size, I think (maybe that was causing some of your issues?).